# Rails - How to pluralize a sentence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pluralize

I know you can pluralize a word in Rails using the pluralize feature.

```
pluralize (3, 'cat')
=> 3 cats
```

But what I'm trying to do is pluralize a sentence that needs to pluralize multiple words.

```
There are <%= Cat.count %> cats
```

The problem with this, is if there is only 1 cat. It would return

```
There are 1 cats
```

Which doesn't make sense gramatically.

It should say

```
There are x cats (if x is not 1)

There is 1 cat (if there is only 1)
```

Problem is, I can't figure out how to pluralize this, since we have two arguments here (is and cat).

Any help will be appreciated.

Maybe something like this?

```
if Cat.count == 1
  puts "There is 1 cat"
else
  puts "There are #{Cat.count} cats"
end
```

Comment: One simple `if-else` statement would do the trick.

Comment: Write a method to parse your sentence and do the right thing, if you need it to be general-purpose, or build the sentence based on the count.

Comment: Is the value in question `Cat.count` or `cat.count`? Which?

Comment: I think this issue is better solved here: stackoverflow.com/questions/1686226

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make use of the [pluralization features](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization) of the `I18n` library by defining count values to translation keys (i.e. `config/locales/en.yml`):

```yaml
en:
  cats:
    one: 'There is one cat.'
    other: 'There are %{count} cats.'
```

Then, in your code (or view, or anywhere else, since `I18n` is globally available)

```
3.times{|i|
  puts I18n.t('cats', count: i)
}
```

will output

```
There are 0 cats.
There is one cat.
There are 2 cats.
```

Comment: The output for 1 should be "There is one cat.", right?

Comment: You are correct, good catch!